# How to iterate through each element in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a 2d numpy array of size 768 x 1024 which contains all the class values of a segmented image.
I have detected pedestrians/vehicles within this array and have got the top left and bottom right coordinate of the bounding box say (381,254) and (387,257).

(381,254) (381,255) ............... (381,257)

(382,254)

.

.

.

(387,254) .................................(387,257)

Each cell under those coordinates have a specific class value (numbers from 1 to 22). The ones that interest me are '4' and '10' which indicates that the bounding box contains a pedestrian or vehicle respectively.

How do I iterate through each element individually (all the elements in row 381 from column 254 to 257 then onto the next row and so on till the bottom right coordinate (387,257)) and check if that particular cell contains the number 4 or 10?

I tried using nested for loop but I'm not able to figure out the logic.

```
x_1 = 381
x_2 = 387
y_1 = 254
y_2 = 257
ROW = []
COL = []
four = 0
ten = 0
other = 0
for rows in range(x_1, x_2):
   ROW.append(rows)
   for cols in range(y_1, y_2):
     COL.append(cols)
     if array[rows][cols] == 4:
        four += 1
     elif array[rows][cols] == 10:
        ten += 1
     else:
        print('random number')
        other += 1
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Bounding box? Python 2D array? I think you should start becoming friends with [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html). You can do this in basic Python (actually, it is good to have done in once) but these tasks will be way easier in numpy/pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
x_1 = 381
x_2 = 387
y_1 = 254
y_2 = 257
ROW = []
COL = []
four = 0
ten = 0
other = 0
for rows in range(x_1, x_2):
   ROW.append(rows)
   for cols in range(y_1, y_2):
     COL.append(cols)
     if 4 in (x_2, y_2):
        four += 1
     elif 10 in (x_2, y_2):
        ten += 1
     else:
        print('random number')
        other += 1
```

It will check if `array[x][y]` contain number 4 or 10. For example, if `array[x][y] == (12, 4)` then `four += 1`.